# PWM speed control of 24V DC Brushless Pump

Tags: arduino, pwm, brushless-dc-motor

I would like to PWM speed control a 24V 2A DC Brushless Pump using an Arduino for my nano-brewery project. I've been searching for a Speed controller on Amazon or Ebay. But, i either find brushed motor controller or three phase controllers. I have only 2 wires on pump. Any recommendations on what I need to purchase? Thank you.

I need to control 3 pumps.

Pump I have: https://www.proflow-dynamics.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/1200x/040ec09b1e35df139433887a97daa66f/w/h/whole_set_with_adapter__1.jpg

Power Supply I have: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B077XDC487/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B077XDC487)

Comment: It looks like the pump is designed to operate from a fixed 24V supply which means it already has a speed controller inside it. You may (or may not) be able to control the speed by varying the input voltage from 24V down to some lower limit which I cannot really predict. Simple PWM control will probably not work well because the built-in speed controller probably has input capacitance. I don't know a nice simple way to control your motor without doing quite a bit of experimentation with it. Maybe search for a variable voltage supply whose output voltage could be controlled from Arduino?

Comment: Please provide a link to the pump specs, not just a picture of it.

Comment: That's just it. I dont find specs for these pumps. These pumps are food grade with stainless steel head for the brewing industry... They are white labelled for sale by various different companies. I purchased it here - https://www.brew-boss.com/product-p/pump-ss-24.htm. These are other links - https://www.brewhardware.com/product_p/topsfloss.htm, https://www.morebeer.com/products/topsflo-td5-beer-pump.html   .. inside the pump it looks like this.. https://www.homebrewtalk.com/forum/attachments/pump_05-jpg.255498/

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the pump voltage , and you shouldn't. Not what they are designed for.
What you can control is the output resistance.  You need dc controlled adjustable valves installed on the output of your pumps. Brewpi, etc should have control for these built in and are relatively inexpensive on the typical sites(AliExpress).  Good luck.
Edit: There are tons of documented builds using this method on homebrewtalk. Not sure what platform or program you're looking to use for your panel but, unless you are coding it yourself, there's detail threads on the usual suspects like brewpi, craftbeerpi and raspberry pints.

Comment: I like this approach.. I need to think about controlling the position of a digital solenoid valve for adjusting the output of the fluid rate.. (instead of the speed of the pump itself.. ) . I need to do major design changes. But, will work on it. Sounds like a better approach coz thats what we do with a manual valve if there is no automation. Anyone else try this?

Comment: Proportional DC clean hydraulic valves can also be cheap or good or not clean.  Consider the pump will start with >5x to 8x rated current until  the speed rises. Does the Pump RPM rise when output flow is blocked or reduce?  Also consider servo ball valves.

Comment: I agree that this is probably a better way to do it. But it is very possible that the pump speed can be controlled by adjusting the voltage. There will be some minimum voltage where the pump will stop running, of course.